# How do I get the newest lowlatency-kernel on 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, kernel, lts, realtime

When installing the linux-lowlatency package on 18.04 LTS, the lowlatency-kernel version 4.15 is installed, while the -generic kernel has been updated to 4.18 since the LTS release.

4.18 linux-lowlatency packages are only available for cosmic and later releases.

Is there any way to automatically get new lowlatency-kernel versions on 18.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install `linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04`, as `linux-lowlatency` will always install the original version, 4.15, in this case.

```
apt-cache show linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04 | grep Depends
Depends: linux-image-lowlatency-hwe-18.04 (= 4.18.0.18.68), linux-headers-lowlatency-hwe-18.04 (= 4.18.0.18.68)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, okay. This was my issue. I did not realise that there were two kernel versions and the hwe-kernel was preinstalled, as uname -r doesn't specify this.