# Resume from suspend error 18.04.4 with kernels 4.15.0-88 and 5.3.0-40

Tags: kernel, suspend

My hardware: laptop HP Elitebook 6930p, Intel Core duo, stock Radeon graphics controller

My OS sw: Ubuntu MATE 18.04.4

problem description:

- with kernel 4.15.0-76 resume from suspend WORKS OKAY, as with all previous kernels since first installation of Ubuntu MATE
- since updating kernel to 4.15.0-88 few weeks ago, resume from suspend DOES NOT WORK, system goes to suspend, but does not resume by pushing the power button, display blinks few times, stays black with cursor in top left corner. Reboot starts system again normally.
- trying to solve problem by upgrading kernel to 5.3.0-40 but resume from suspend DOES NOT WORK, same problem like with kernel 4.15.0-88. Reboot starts system again normally.
- now having all mentioned kernels installed, and when selecting kernel 4.15.0-76 in grub, and starting system, resume from suspend works okay when pushing power button.

Seen many similar problem description at site, but not found working solution so far.

What should I do to fix this?

Data check: **Kernel 4.15.0-76**

> sh@HP-MATE:~$ uname -a
>
> Linux HP-MATE 4.15.0-76-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:24:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ sudo blkid
>
> /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/sda1: UUID="0b348867-07da-457d-a3bd-53c7eadc9ac4" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="78d29c15-01"
>   /dev/sda5: UUID="PoP2Ze-xEsB-TRpm-R9iz-10Ed-hv8a-mp8Gq5" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="78d29c15-05"
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-root: UUID="431a67b1-bfd1-4f23-b898-41774cf7bb22" TYPE="ext4"
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1: UUID="fff000a6-83df-4543-86bb-5ae567068ccd" TYPE="swap"
>   /dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ free -h
>
> total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
>   Mem:  3,8G        888M        1,2G         28M     1,8G        2,6G
>   Swap: 4,0G          0B        4,0G
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
>
> RESUME=UUID=fff000a6-83df-4543-86bb-5ae567068ccd
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ cat /etc/fstab
>
> /etc/fstab: static file system information.
>
> Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that
>   works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
>
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
>   "#/boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation"
>   UUID=0b348867-07da-457d-a3bd-53c7eadc9ac4 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

Data check: **Kernel 4.15.0-88**

> sh@HP-MATE:~$ uname -a
>
> Linux HP-MATE 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC
>   2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ sudo blkid
>
> /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/sda1: UUID="0b348867-07da-457d-a3bd-53c7eadc9ac4" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="78d29c15-01"
>   /dev/sda5: UUID="PoP2Ze-xEsB-TRpm-R9iz-10Ed-hv8a-mp8Gq5" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="78d29c15-05"
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-root: UUID="431a67b1-bfd1-4f23-b898-41774cf7bb22" TYPE="ext4"
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1: UUID="fff000a6-83df-4543-86bb-5ae567068ccd" TYPE="swap"
>   /dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ free -h
>
> total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
>   Mem: 3,8G        815M        2,1G         23M    897M        2,8G
>   Swap: 4,0G          0B        4,0G
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
>
> RESUME=UUID=fff000a6-83df-4543-86bb-5ae567068ccd
>
> sh@HP-MATE:~$ cat /etc/fstab
>
> /etc/fstab: static file system information.
>
> Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
>
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-root /               ext4  errors=remount-ro 0       1
>   "#/boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation"
>   UUID=0b348867-07da-457d-a3bd-53c7eadc9ac4 /boot           ext2   defaults        0       2
>   /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: Sorry for asking that, but why do you need newer kernels?

Comment: I always try to keep my systems (I mean all systems, Linux and Win) updated by installing the latests stock updates, no matter if it is kernel or other sw update, for security reasons. I do not want to upgrade kernels above stock, as I have bad experiences with older Ubuntu Gnome versions with not working kernel upgrades. Stock kernels have worked so far well, but this time not.

Comment: I use `5.3.0-40-lowlatency` on my laptop now. You could try it also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140575/how-do-i-get-the-newest-lowlatency-kernel-on-18-04-lts

Comment: I have 5.3.0-40-generic installed now, and problem occurs with that kernel too. What does lowlatency do better to generic?

Comment: It's just hope it could magically work even if it is not expected)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `free -h` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Hello. I tried to edit but the formatting rules are bit strange for a newbie... Hope to have all info available.