# Single CPU always at 100%, lagging | Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, cpu

I bought a new Laptop which was running fine for about one or two weeks. I can't exactly recall a certain trigger but I now have the problem that one CPU core is almost always running near 100% and the computer is lagging.

I use a dual boot from the beginning on, Windows 10 however is running fine.

Specs:

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U

GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile

16GB RAM

I looked at some other posts but the suggested fixes didn't work for me so far.
I made sure the computer uses the NVidia Graphics Card and to my best knowledge newest drivers are installed. I also tried switching to Kubuntu Desktop but the problem remained.

My main problem is, that I can't find the process which is causing the permanent CPU usage.
I restarted the computer and let it sit idle for a few minutes, occasionally the CPU usage went down but usually it stays high. (See 2 attached picture)

When I run any other program as well the lagging gets worse, playing a youtube video makes the mouse itself lag heavily and the CPU is almost running at 100% constantly (See picture)

I am thankful for any help and will gladly provide any data / output from commands that are needed, since I want to fix this issue.

Thank you very much

EDIT:
The output of

```
ps aux --sort=-pcpu | head
```

is

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1602 15.0  0.7 576228 129056 tty2    Sl+  10:24   6:20 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
lars      5880 13.5  2.2 3817104 365864 tty2   Sl+  10:46   2:47 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
lars      1780 12.4  2.9 4400160 486128 tty2   Rl+  10:24   5:13 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
lars      6139 10.0  1.2 2760008 209576 tty2   Sl+  10:47   2:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7500 -prefMapSize 217531 -parentBuildID 20200403170909 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 5880 true tab
lars      2159  5.4  0.2 656356 47904 tty2     Sl+  10:24   2:16 gnome-system-monitor
lars      6776  4.7  1.0 2663220 170720 tty2   Sl+  11:02   0:13 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 13 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7823 -prefMapSize 217531 -parentBuildID 20200403170909 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 5880 true tab
root      1386  2.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:24   0:56 [irq/152-nvidia]
lars      6730  1.2  1.2 2710580 202384 tty2   Sl+  11:01   0:04 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 12 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7752 -prefMapSize 217531 -parentBuildID 20200403170909 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 5880 true tab
lars      6003  1.0  1.1 34232032 191064 tty2  Sl+  10:46   0:13 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 6684 -prefMapSize 217531 -parentBuildID 20200403170909 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 5880 true tab
```

I tried unplugging all USB devices but it didn't change anything

EDIT2:

Pictures of htop after fresh install:
[image: Xorg]
[image: gnome-shell]

EDIT3:
Output of `pstree -l`

```
systemd─┬─ModemManager───2*[{ModemManager}]
        ├─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
        │                └─2*[{NetworkManager}]
        ├─accounts-daemon───2*[{accounts-daemon}]
        ├─acpid
        ├─anacron
        ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
        ├─bluetoothd
        ├─boltd───2*[{boltd}]
        ├─colord───2*[{colord}]
        ├─cron
        ├─cups-browsed───2*[{cups-browsed}]
        ├─cupsd
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─deja-dup-monito───3*[{deja-dup-monito}]
        ├─gdm3─┬─gdm-session-wor─┬─gdm-wayland-ses─┬─gnome-session-b─┬─gnome-shell─┬─Xwayland───9*[{Xwayland}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 │             ├─ibus-daemon─┬─ibus-dconf───3*[{ibus-dconf}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 │             │             ├─ibus-engine-sim───2*[{ibus-engine-sim}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 │             │             └─2*[{ibus-daemon}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 │             └─26*[{gnome-shell}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-a11y-settin───3*[{gsd-a11y-settin}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-clipboard───3*[{gsd-clipboard}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-color───4*[{gsd-color}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-datetime───2*[{gsd-datetime}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-housekeepin───2*[{gsd-housekeepin}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-keyboard───4*[{gsd-keyboard}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-media-keys───4*[{gsd-media-keys}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-mouse───2*[{gsd-mouse}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-power───4*[{gsd-power}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-print-notif───2*[{gsd-print-notif}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-rfkill───2*[{gsd-rfkill}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-screensaver───2*[{gsd-screensaver}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-sharing───3*[{gsd-sharing}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-smartcard───4*[{gsd-smartcard}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-sound───3*[{gsd-sound}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-wacom───3*[{gsd-wacom}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 ├─gsd-xsettings───4*[{gsd-xsettings}]
        │      │                 │                 │                 └─3*[{gnome-session-b}]
        │      │                 │                 └─2*[{gdm-wayland-ses}]
        │      │                 └─2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
        │      ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─gdm-x-session─┬─Xorg───2*[{Xorg}]
        │      │                 │               ├─lxsession─┬─lxpanel─┬─firefox─┬─RDD Process───3*[{RDD Process}]
        │      │                 │               │           │         │         ├─2*[Web Content───33*[{Web Content}]]
        │      │                 │               │           │         │         ├─Web Content───35*[{Web Content}]
        │      │                 │               │           │         │         ├─4*[Web Content───34*[{Web Content}]]
        │      │                 │               │           │         │         ├─Web Content───47*[{Web Content}]
        │      │                 │               │           │         │         ├─WebExtensions───29*[{WebExtensions}]
        │      │                 │               │           │         │         └─85*[{firefox}]
        │      │                 │               │           │         └─4*[{lxpanel}]
        │      │                 │               │           ├─lxpolkit───2*[{lxpolkit}]
        │      │                 │               │           ├─openbox───2*[{openbox}]
        │      │                 │               │           ├─pcmanfm───2*[{pcmanfm}]
        │      │                 │               │           ├─ssh-agent
        │      │                 │               │           └─2*[{lxsession}]
        │      │                 │               └─2*[{gdm-x-session}]
        │      │                 └─2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
        │      └─2*[{gdm3}]
        ├─ibus-x11───3*[{ibus-x11}]
        ├─irqbalance───{irqbalance}
        ├─2*[kerneloops]
        ├─menu-cached───2*[{menu-cached}]
        ├─networkd-dispat───{networkd-dispat}
        ├─nm-applet───3*[{nm-applet}]
        ├─nvidia-persiste
        ├─packagekitd───2*[{packagekitd}]
        ├─polkitd───2*[{polkitd}]
        ├─pulseaudio───2*[{pulseaudio}]
        ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
        ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
        ├─snapd───17*[{snapd}]
        ├─ssh-agent
        ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
        │         ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
        │         │                 └─3*[{at-spi-bus-laun}]
        │         ├─at-spi2-registr───2*[{at-spi2-registr}]
        │         ├─dbus-daemon
        │         ├─ibus-portal───2*[{ibus-portal}]
        │         ├─pulseaudio───2*[{pulseaudio}]
        │         └─xdg-permission-───2*[{xdg-permission-}]
        ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
        │         ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
        │         │                 └─3*[{at-spi-bus-laun}]
        │         ├─at-spi2-registr───2*[{at-spi2-registr}]
        │         ├─dbus-daemon
        │         ├─dconf-service───2*[{dconf-service}]
        │         ├─gnome-screensav───3*[{gnome-screensav}]
        │         ├─gnome-terminal-─┬─bash───htop
        │         │                 ├─bash───pstree
        │         │                 └─4*[{gnome-terminal-}]
        │         ├─goa-daemon───3*[{goa-daemon}]
        │         ├─goa-identity-se───3*[{goa-identity-se}]
        │         ├─gvfs-afc-volume───3*[{gvfs-afc-volume}]
        │         ├─gvfs-goa-volume───2*[{gvfs-goa-volume}]
        │         ├─gvfs-gphoto2-vo───2*[{gvfs-gphoto2-vo}]
        │         ├─gvfs-mtp-volume───2*[{gvfs-mtp-volume}]
        │         ├─gvfs-udisks2-vo───2*[{gvfs-udisks2-vo}]
        │         ├─gvfsd─┬─gvfsd-trash───2*[{gvfsd-trash}]
        │         │       └─2*[{gvfsd}]
        │         ├─gvfsd-fuse───5*[{gvfsd-fuse}]
        │         ├─indicator-appli───2*[{indicator-appli}]
        │         ├─indicator-sound───3*[{indicator-sound}]
        │         ├─xdg-desktop-por───4*[{xdg-desktop-por}]
        │         ├─xdg-desktop-por───2*[{xdg-desktop-por}]
        │         ├─xdg-document-po───5*[{xdg-document-po}]
        │         ├─xdg-permission-───2*[{xdg-permission-}]
        │         ├─xfce4-notifyd───2*[{xfce4-notifyd}]
        │         └─xfconfd
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-resolve
        ├─systemd-timesyn───{systemd-timesyn}
        ├─systemd-udevd
        ├─thermald───{thermald}
        ├─udisksd───4*[{udisksd}]
        ├─unattended-upgr───{unattended-upgr}
        ├─update-notifier───3*[{update-notifier}]
        ├─upowerd───2*[{upowerd}]
        ├─whoopsie───2*[{whoopsie}]
        ├─wpa_supplicant
        └─xfce4-power-man───2*[{xfce4-power-man}]
```

EDIT: usage with ubuntu on wayland
[image: Htop on Ubuntut on Wayland]

Output of `journalctl -f`

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-04-16 14:32:57 CEST. --
Apr 16 18:03:57 yoshua systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 16 18:03:57 yoshua dbus-daemon[885]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 16 18:03:57 yoshua systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr 16 18:03:57 yoshua nautilus[2465]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Apr 16 18:04:06 yoshua eog[2493]: Failed to open file '/home/lars/.cache/thumbnails/normal/bd89ad6e4e39e613a580a0a13dc30c75.png': No such file or directory
Apr 16 18:04:16 yoshua org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1512]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-234ms)
Apr 16 18:04:16 yoshua org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1512]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-170ms)
Apr 16 18:04:16 yoshua org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1512]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-183ms)
Apr 16 18:04:20 yoshua org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1512]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce: offset negative (-1ms)
Apr 16 18:04:20 yoshua org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1512]: libinput error: client bug: timer event11 debounce short: offset negative (-15ms)
Apr 16 18:05:55 yoshua dbus-daemon[885]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.121' (uid=1000 pid=2149 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window " label="unconfined")
Apr 16 18:05:55 yoshua systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 16 18:05:55 yoshua dbus-daemon[885]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 16 18:05:55 yoshua systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr 16 18:05:55 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:05:56 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:05:57 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:05:58 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:05:59 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:05:59 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:06:00 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:06:00 yoshua gvfsd[1528]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Apr 16 18:06:10 yoshua kernel: [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=22662 end=22663) time 111 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1072, end 1080
Apr 16 18:06:13 yoshua kernel: [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=22830 end=22831) time 357 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1072, end 1096
Apr 16 18:06:45 yoshua kernel: [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=24753 end=24754) time 239 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1066, end 1079
Apr 16 18:06:51 yoshua gnome-shell[1512]: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenu' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
```

EDIT:
It is working fine now. No more peaks from one core, all are continuously working on a small level. The last thing I did was what @Gryu recommended:
I switched into tty. Switched to lightdm `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` which didn't change anything. I restarted and switched back to gdm3 via the same command.

I don't understand how this helped, but I am happy.
Thanks you very much!

EDIT:
The way I see it, I can avoid the problem if I shutdown using the physical power-off button. I don't know what to think about it, I just leave the info here.

Comment: you write " I can't exactly recall a certain trigger but I now have the problem"... Here is where to digg

Comment: well, as I said I only got the computer and was installing many libraries over the time. I don't think I have a chance to find it that way, to be honest.

Comment: Hmm... In the first htop pic, Xorg seems to be lagging you! Click on logout and go to bottom right, click on gear icon, click on ubuntu on wayland! Does that fix it?

Comment: @SambhavSurana I just switched to Ubuntu on wayland, but there is no difference.

Comment: Ok can you add picture of htop on ubuntu on wayland

Comment: @SambhavSurana just added one, it seems that only the gnome-shell is causing the usage then

Comment: I have the same problem. Weirdly we have the same graphics card and CPU. Is yours also a HP Laptop?  My setup:
My hardware setup:

Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2 SSD harddisk
SSD harddisk
Software/driver/kernel setup:

nvidia-driver-435 (proprietary)
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Kernel: 5.3.0-51-generic
Gnome 3.28.2

So far I still haven't figured out what triggered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try one or few of:

- Use `htop` to see what processes load your system and kill them to see what will happen: `killall processname` or `killall -9 processname` to kill it forcefully.
- Reinstall a package of a program or command that loads it intensively by: `sudo apt purge package_name && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install package_name`
- Update/Install CPU mocrocode firmware: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install intel-microcode microcode.ctl`
- Install [a different kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140575/how-do-i-get-the-newest-lowlatency-kernel-on-18-04-lts) and try it
- Install a different desktop manager: `gdm3` instead of `lightdm` or vice versa, purging previous: `sudo apt install gdm3 && sudo apt purge lightdm`
- Install a different desktop environment: `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` and try it.
- Purge `xubuntu-desktop` or `xfce4` as I was noticing that system lags when it is installed, however, not used: `sudo apt purge xubuntu-desktop && sudo apt purge xfce*`

My `pstree -l` on 19.10 with gdm3:

```
├─gdm3─┬─gdm-session-wor─┬─gdm-x-session─┬─Xorg───{Xorg}
│      │                 │               ├─gnome-session-b───3*[{gnome-session-b}]
│      │                 │               └─2*[{gdm-x-session}]
│      │                 └─2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
│      ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─gdm-x-session─┬─Xorg───{Xorg}
│      │                 │               ├─gnome-session-b─┬─ssh-agent
│      │                 │               │                 └─2*[{gnome-session-b}]
│      │                 │               └─2*[{gdm-x-session}]
│      │                 └─2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
│      └─2*[{gdm3}]
```

My `pstree -l` on 18.04 VM:

```
├─lightdm─┬─Xorg───5*[{Xorg}]
│         ├─lightdm─┬─lxsession─┬─lxpanel─┬─lxterminal─┬─bash───pstree
│         │         │           │         │            ├─bash
│         │         │           │         │            └─2*[{lxterminal}]
│         │         │           │         └─4*[{lxpanel}]
│         │         │           ├─lxpolkit───2*[{lxpolkit}]
│         │         │           ├─openbox───2*[{openbox}]
│         │         │           ├─pcmanfm───2*[{pcmanfm}]
│         │         │           ├─ssh-agent
│         │         │           └─2*[{lxsession}]
│         │         └─2*[{lightdm}]
│         └─2*[{lightdm}]
```

Run also `journalctl -f` in a terminal to see what happens. Maybe some gnome-settings-daemon (gsd) constantly trying to do something and fails throwing errors and it takes the whole core.

Switch to lightdm to see if something will be changed, but do it on some tty: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>: `sudo apt purge gdm3 && sudo apt install lightdm`. You could also do it without gdm3 removing: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` if you have it installed.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
reboot
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Maybe switching to lightdm fourth and to gdm3 back somehow changes gdm3 configuration modified previously by different graphical configuration tools.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu, however the problem is still there. It seems like it is a combination of gnome shell and/or Xorg which is causing the high usage. 
Do you see a way how it can still be there after reinstalling?

I will try to attach pictures of ```htop```

Comment: outputs of ```htop``` now in main post

Comment: Try to install or update your CPU microcode: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install intel-microcode`. Seems strangely. After fresh install have you upgraded packages? What `uname -r` shows?

Comment: hm, ```intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20191115.1ubuntu0.18.04.2)```

I restarted but it's still the same

Comment: Yes, I just upgraded everything.

```uname -r``` returns ```5.3.0-46-generic```

Comment: Ok. I would recommend trying different kernels also. It could be a hardware specific kernel bug.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I will look into this. 

I know this is an Ubuntu-forum, but do you think I would have similar problems with another distribution?

Comment: I think you could try, but try different kernels and `lubuntu-desktop` before it, so we could know if gnome has an issue. You could also post in your question output of `pstree -l` command copying and pasting text from terminal.

Comment: I tried different desktops, which took a while. It feels a little less laggy, but CPU usage is at this high level when using ```LXDE``` or ```lubuntu```
I pasted the output of ```pstree -l``` in the main post.
I didn't try different kernels yet as this might take me a little.

Comment: Run also `journalctl -f` in terminal to see what happens. Maybe some gnome-settings-daemon (gsd) constantly trying to do something and fails throwing errors and it takes the whole core.

Comment: Did any of this fix your problem? You accepted the answer, but I don't see what exactly worked for you. Facing the same issue nothing so far has worked for me.

Comment: @Robin Changing to lightdm fourth and to gdm3 back

Comment: @Robin I edited my initial post several times. In the end I wasn't able to find the exact root of the problem. I still have the issue occasionally. But I can reliably fix it by shutting off the laptop with the physical power button (!). Try this.

Comment: Have you trying gdm restarting? `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`? And, have you tried other desktop environment?

Comment: @Gryu ```sudo systemctl restart gdm3``` worked like a charm! How, why, can you elaborate on that? When I ran the command whatever ran there got stuck and I manually rebootet with the power button. Then did it again, again got stuck, rebootet. So I was less than optimistic. But, now for 2 days, I haven't had problems. Huge thanks!!

Comment: It's very difficult to say what's the cause of this issue. The command just restarts display manager. It could mean some software sometimes causes it to work unstable. It's not wide spread issue, so maybe some combination of some hardware, drivers and software causes it. In my case I do not have such configuration, so I could not say exactly what causes it.

Comment: Hmm now the Problem is back, as bad as ever. Reappeared after a reboot. But I guess that was to be expected. Thank you for the Hotfix anyways!

Comment: happens to me in recent latest kernels only if i plugged external monitor to my laptop. i believe it is xorg stuff